# Visual Studio 2008 'find in files' reg-ex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008

Really easy question for somebody, I know it’s really simple but I just can’t work out how to search for two matching strings using the regex ‘find in files’ search in Visual Studio 2008.
So for, if I have lines:

```
One twoo three four five
On tw three four five
One two thre fourr five
One two three fur five
```

I want to search for ‘two’ and ‘four’ (so returning only the first and third lines). Thanks.

Comment: None, it's the 'find in files' dialogue in vs2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just `(?=.*two)(?=.*four)`?

Comment: Near enough! It didnt work in vs2008 (remember it isnt proper regex) but you set me on right path. In the end it was:

    (.*two)(.*four)